# PHP Array Restructuration

Tags: php, arrays

I have pairs of keys identified by their respective ID like this:

```
array(
    'key_a_0' => $a,
    'key_a_1' => $a,
    'key_b_0' => $b,
    'key_b_1' => $b
    )
```

I need this structure:

```
array(
    '0' => array(
        'key_a' => $a,
        'key_b' => $b
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'key_a' => $a,
        'key_b' => $b
    )
)
```

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: how was the original array create, often better to fix it there

Comment: Modifying  the original array would bring too many complications. It's unserialized data from an option table. The original flat array structure is actually what keep the options initialization and sanitization job simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided this is exactly how all the data is present as, and stays as, this would then be simple to amend into the format you require with a simple `foreach` loop.

```
$new = array();

foreach($data as $key => $variable){
    list($name,$var,$index) = explode("_", $key);
    $new[$index][$name . '_' . $var] = $variable;
}
```

This returns;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key_a] => 5
            [key_b] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key_a] => 5
            [key_b] => 10
        )

)
```

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#1tFU0EmrK)

---

Ideally - you'd want to set your array structure at creation, [*as Dagon said*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288534/php-array-restructuration/37288745#comment62101953_37288534).

Comment: The combination of list() and explode() make perfectly the job and keep the code simple and elegant. Thank you !!

Comment: @opportus Pleasure mate! Glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the job. This assumes, however, that the initial array comes in a specific order and that order is what is expected within each nested array in the final array, and that the keys in the initial array are always in that format.

```
$a = 5;
$b = 10;

$aRawArray = array(
    'key_a_0' => $a,
    'key_a_1' => $a,
    'key_b_0' => $b,
    'key_b_1' => $b,
);

$aFormattedArray = array();

foreach ($aRawArray as $sKey => $mValue) {
    $aKeyParts = explode('_', $sKey);
    $sExtractedKey = $aKeyParts[2];
    $sNewKey = $aKeyParts[0] . '_' . $aKeyParts[1];

    if (!isset($aFormattedArray[$sExtractedKey])) {
        $aFormattedArray[$sExtractedKey] = array();
    }

    $aFormattedArray[$sExtractedKey][$sNewKey] = $mValue;   
}

var_dump($aFormattedArray);
```